# Why does the 40 minute question limit apply to both main and meta sites?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, per-site-meta, rate-limiting

I asked a question on Movies & TV about a series that did not have a tag yet.  Not having the 300 rep to add a new tag, I posed the question with the closest tag I could find, and then went to meta to ask someone to add the tag...

Only to find out that I was rate limited on meta as well (at least from the iOS app).  I wanted to ask for community help on meta, since I do not believe this issue warrants a mod flag.

Why does the question rate limit apply to meta questions as well?  Is it to prevent new users from (incorrectly) flooding meta with bad, potentially off-topic questions?  That's great for keeping new users in check, but hurts more experienced users wishing to start a discussion on meta around their question.

You can see my original post on Movies.SE [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/revisions/63407/1), as well as a second time I ran into this on ReverseEngineering.SE [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/13965/17972).